# Basic configuration for sending message on librdkafka Producer

Tags: c++, apache-kafka

Is there any other configuration we need to do when sending a message to topic in Apache Kafka?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <librdkafka/rdkafkacpp.h>

int main() {
    std::string brokers = "localhost:9092";
    std::string topic = "thirdtopic";
    std::string errstr;
    // std::string conf_dump;

    RdKafka::Conf *conf = RdKafka::Conf::create(RdKafka::Conf::CONF_GLOBAL);
    RdKafka::Conf *tconf = RdKafka::Conf::create(RdKafka::Conf::CONF_TOPIC);
    conf->set("bootstrap.servers", brokers, errstr);
    // conf->get("bootstrap.servers",conf_dump);
    // std::cout<<"Conf dump: "<<conf_dump<<std::endl;

    RdKafka::Producer *producer = RdKafka::Producer::create(conf, errstr);
    delete conf;

    // std::cout << "Created producer " << producer->name() << std::endl;

    RdKafka::Topic *rd_topic = RdKafka::Topic::create(producer, topic, tconf, errstr);
        std::string message;
        std::cout << "Enter the Message or type 'exit': ";
        std::getline(std::cin, message);

        RdKafka::ErrorCode resp = producer->produce(rd_topic, RdKafka::Topic::PARTITION_UA, RdKafka::Producer::RK_MSG_COPY,
                                           const_cast<char *>(message.c_str()), message.size(), NULL, NULL);

        if (resp != RdKafka::ErrorCode::ERR_NO_ERROR) {
            std::cerr << "Failed to produce message: " << RdKafka::err2str(resp) << std::endl;
        } else {
        std::cout << "Message produced: " << message << std::endl;
        }
    delete tconf;
    delete rd_topic;
    delete producer;

    return 0;
}
```

The Error i am facing is :

```
[admin@krishnaraj Producer]$ build/sender

Enter the Message or type 'exit': the matter of time

Failed to produce message: Local: Invalid argument or configuration........
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce with the bitnami/kafka Docker image. (after adding in the configuration for external clients). Is your Kafka cluster configured correctly? I do get a warning about needing to call `producer->flush(...)` but you're not there yet.

Comment: Yeah! I configured kafka cluster correctly and cretaed a topic called "thirdtopic".
I can't get it when you say bitnami/kafka Docker image can you please elaborate.
This is the producer code that simply contains sending a simple message to the topic .

Comment: I am far too lazy/busy to set up a Kafka cluster from scratch so I just grabbed a [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/kafka/#!). Your code ran succesfully against that basic configuration. So the error must be in your cluster config.

Comment: [root@tms-devkit bu]# ./sender 
Created producer rdkafka#producer-1
%3|1700661322.486|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/1]: 127.0.0.1:9092/1: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Connection refused
%3|1700661322.486|ERROR|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:127.0.0.1:9092/1]: 127.0.0.1:9092/1: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Connection refused
Enter the Message or type 'exit': dcasd
Message produced: hi i am ------and the message is also not receiving in the consumer.so how do you say it is working?can you please elaborate?

Comment: These error caused while i connected my code to docker container............ previous error is solve "Invalid argument or configuration" instead i got the above........

Comment: can you please share yours are tell me what to do?

Comment: I just followed [the instructions](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/kafka/#!) under "Apache Kafka development setup example" and "Accessing Apache Kafka with internal and external clients"

Comment: can you please share your Producer and Consumer code ........It is Possible?

Comment: I just used your program